# style function called twice in openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I wonder why my style function is called twice for each cluster added to the layer. This is the code I have:

```
function calculateClusterInfo(feature, resolution) {
    //This function called twice
    var style, size, circleRadius, circleFill, zoomMapID;
    size = feature.get('features').length;
    var style = styleCache[size];
    if (!style) {
    if (size > 1) {
        if (size < 10) { // small cluster
            circleRadius = 30;
            circleFill = new ol.style.Fill({
                color: [181, 226, 140, 0.6]
            });
        } 
        style = [new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: circleRadius,
                fill: circleFill
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                textAlign: "start",
                textBaseline: "middle",
                font: "bold 12px helvetica",                    
                text: size,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: "#000000"}),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: "#ffffff", width: 4}),
                offsetX: 0,
                offsetY: 0,
                rotation: 0
            })
        })];          
        return style;
    } else {
        style = [feature.get('features')[0].getStyle()];
        return style;
    }
    }
};
```

I cannot figure out why style function is called twice.

Comment: can you post a more complete example in a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? If your vector source object has an option for different loading strategies you might check if changing it from tile loading (which could be generating the double trigger) to bounding box loading solves the problem.